# Storing data on Post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I'm displaying data say 10000 records using paging with 1000/page. I have a checkbox to select a particular row(s) among those 1000 records. Now in the first page, user can select some rows and go to next page and select some more records and so on. How can I store records of first page when I go to next page and records selected in 1st and 2nd page when I go to third page. Pls suggest some best way to do this.

Comment: 1000 records per page, are you sure that the users need so many records? It'll impact the page's loading time massively. According to your question, you could use `Session`.

Comment: data retrieval is not a problem for me but storing data has become a problem. Can Session handle many records ?? and how it will be when it comes to something like viewstate?? I juslike to knw what are the different ways that I can implement ... Thnaks for your response @TimSchmelter

Comment: Session is Server-memory by default. So you can store anything there. It's scope is the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a database? If you are then what you can do is store a temp table in the database that will store every record that has been checked (and if need be the some form of user id or the ip address if more than one person is intending to use this page) and then when the user loads a new page use the page change event to check if any of the new records have already been checked and then use this table when performing the action that is done with all the checked records

I would suggest this approach over a session as sessions are not designed to be used where there is a potential for 10000 records to be the value

Comment: We dont have database on our side. Its handled by other group.